# $T(v_1), \ldots,T(v_k)$ are independent if and only if $\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)\cap \ker(T)=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with this:

> If $T:V\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation and $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a linearly independent set in $V$, prove that $T(v_1), T(v_2),\ldots,T(v_k)$  are independent in $W$ if and only if 
>   $$\operatorname{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)\cap \ker(T)=\{0\}.$$

I know how to prove that a independent set transforms to a independent set, but how do I show that this intersection equals the zero vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v=c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n\in\mathrm{ker}~T$, noting that also $v\in\mathrm{span}~\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, then $$T(v)=T(c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n)=c_1T(v_1)+\cdots+c_nT(v_n)=0$$
implies $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$ since $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)$ are linear independent. It follows that $\mathrm{span}~\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\bigcap\mathrm{ker}~T=\{0\}$. The other side is immediately obtained from the equation.

Comment: nice, that is actually what i have come up with but i was blind to see the answer is right infront of me since T(v) = 0. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the subspace $S$ spanned by your vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$. Then, if the condition holds, you have an isomorphism $T_S$ from $S \to T(S) \subseteq W$. For an isomorphism you have $\ker T_S = \{0\}$, but

$$\{0\} = \ker T_S = S \cap \ker T = \langle v_1,\dots,v_k \rangle \cap \ker T,$$
so this gives the result.

Comment: BIS can you explain why an isomorphism implies kerTs = (0v) ? we didnt study morphisms so its a little hard for me to understand your answer. thanks!

Comment: Oh ok, a linear map  $\phi: V \to W$ is an isomorphism, when it is surjective and injective. in this case, surjective means that for every element $w \in W$ there is (at least) one element $v\in V$ that is the preimage under $\phi$, so $\phi(v) = w$. Injective means that every two elements $v,v' \in V$ that are mapped to the same element under $\phi$, so $\phi(v) = \phi(v')$ are in fact the same $v = v'$. But if $\phi(v) = \phi(v')$, then by linear mapping you get $\phi(v - v') = 0$. Therefore we can restrict ourselves to $\phi$ is injective iff. $\ker \phi = \{0\}$.

Comment: great, thanks BIS

Comment: @user2970357 You're welcome! Feel free to mark my post as an answer, if it helped you!